# How to get custom Pen color?

Tags: vb.net

I tried it, but its not working here is my code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox3_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Paint
    Dim pencolor As String
    pencolor = "89; 179; 105"
    Dim s(1) As Integer
    Dim f(1) As Integer
    Dim pen As Pen = Pens.pencolor
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a Custom Colour on your Pen, you need to create the Brush for your pen first.

For this example, I assumed the RGB colour values being the sequence in your string.

```
    Dim r As Integer = 89
    Dim g As Integer = 179
    Dim b As Integer = 105
    Dim customColour As Color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
    Using customBrush As New SolidBrush(customColour)
        Using customPen As New Pen(customBrush)
            ' use the custom pen...
        End Using
    End Using
```

The Brush is created with the custom colour, and the Brush is then used to create the custom Pen. When you use the Pen it will be in the colour you defined by its R, G, B values

**Edit** *(thanks to Ahmed Abdelhameed for the reminder about the other constructor)*

A `Pen` can also be created without a Brush by simply specifying the required colour in its constructor:

```
Dim customPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))
```

Comment: You don't need the brush. You can call `New Pen(customColour)` directly, or even `New Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thank you for the reminder about the other constructors. I often forget about that due to my habits/experience of using them.